# Asymptotic for implicitly given function

Tags: asymptotics

Function $n(s)$ is given implicitly as $n! = s$. How can I find an asymptotic for $n(s)$? I cannot understand, how can I make an explicit function from this to calculate an asymptotic, as there is no reverse operation for factorial (I mean, like root is reversal to pow, and so on).

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the Stirling Approximation to the factorial. To get information about  the growth of $n$ in terms of $s$, you will need asymptotic information about the Lambert function.

Answer (score 0):

From Stirling's approximation, you know that (for $n\to\infty$)
$$s(n) \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}e \right)^n.$$
The task is to invert this asymptotic relation.

Note that the dominant part reads $s\sim n^n$, i.e., $\log s \sim n \log n$ and $\log\log s \sim \log n + \log\log n$. As the first term dominates, we obtain the first approximation
$$n(s) \sim \log s.$$

A better approximation reads
$$n \sim \frac{\log s}{\log\log s}$$ and so on.